# Select first or last n groups after applying "group by"

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I want to extract specific number of groups after applying group by column. For example first 2 or 3 groups.

I have a data frame:

```
id gender value
1  f      1123 
1  f      10
2  m      123
2  m      154  
2  m      165
3  m      654  
3  m      987
4  f      7654
4  f      7654
4  f      7654
...  ...  ....
```

I want something like this

```
id gender value
2  m      123
2  m      154 
3  m      654  
3  m      987
... .. ...
```

My code is:

```
dtFrame2 = dtFrame.groupby('id').head(2)
dtFrameMale = dtFrame2.loc[dtFrame2.gender=='male']
temp = maleGroups.filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
```

The last statement gives me all the groups with two row but after that I want to extract first two, three or n number of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
In [60]: s = df[df['gender'] == 'm'].groupby('id').size()

In [61]: s.name = 'size'

In [62]: df2 = df.join(s, on='id')

In [63]: df2[df2['size'] == 2]
Out[63]: 
   id gender  value  size
5   3      m    654     2
6   3      m    987     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but there is one addition I want to make for example if there are many instances of such kind then I can get it through this statement df2[df2['size'] == 2][:2*numberofInstances].